# Does tag-it work on textarea HTML element?

Tags: textarea, tag-it

I am using tag-it for my application. My requirement is that I should create tag-it tags and put these tags in a textarea element. I am choosing textarea over input because textarea can support newline.

I have gone through http://aehlke.github.io/tag-it/examples.html, but I notice that it supports only input element. I have also played around with the code and noticed the same.

Does tag-it work on textarea HTML element?

Looking forward to your response

Answer (score 0):

The tag-it library works on input elements. One would, perhaps, have to modify their library in order to accommodate the textarea element.

Another alternative for tag-it would be to use tageditor library https://goodies.pixabay.com/jquery/tag-editor/demo.html as they support textarea HTML elements as well